# Adding a new page to a GitHub wiki using Gollum

Tags: gollum-wiki

Months back I started populating a wiki for someone else's GitHub repo.

I put instructions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathbox/vKkMknqa7rg).

Yesterday I decided I wanted to add a new page. Nobody has modified the wiki in the meanwhile so I figured I can just repeat those instructions from...

- **Make the edits:**
  :

So I run gollum from `/path/to/MathBox/mathbox.wiki/` (which currently contains a `Home.md` and `Slides.md` which correctly reflects the wiki as is), launch my browser at `localhost:4567`, and add a new page by adding `[[foo]]` to the homepage, saving it, clicking it.

Which opens it up as blank page in edit mode, and I then add some dummy text, save, quit browser, quit gollum.

But the files in the current folder haven't changed. `Home.md` should have an extra line, and there should be a new `Foo.md` file containing my dummy text.  But nothing!

And even stranger, running Gollum again shows the wiki in its new state. So my changes are getting recorded somewhere. But as it is not in the working folder, GitHub Desktop doesn't grok that I have made modifications.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Gollum reads and stores files on a git repository, **it doesn't read from uncommitted files stored in the current directory**.

When you are creating a new file using its internal editor it will create a file with the content and will commit it to the local repository.

But when you create a file with an external editor, **you have to commit it** so gollum can read it from a a git repository.